# Why doesn't this drop down menu work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I've download the [Refresh template by Styleshout.com](http://www.styleshout.com/templates/preview/Refresh1-0/index.html) since I really like it. But unfortunately, there was no drop down menu in it, only a normal menu.

So I tried to integrate a drop down menu [which I found a nice tutorial for](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/).

It does almost work - almost. Here's the result: [the template on my webspace](http://wp1080088.wp029.webpack.hosteurope.de/Refresh1-1/).

The menus are opened - but at the wrong location. Why? What's wrong with my implementation? All 3 drop down lists are opened under the first item.

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

PS: Here's the code:

```
####################
####### HTML #######
####################
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Nav #1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Nav #1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav #1.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Nav #2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Nav #2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav #2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Nav #3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Nav #3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav #3.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

####################
#### JAVASCRIPT ####
####################
sfHover = function() {
    var sfEls = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("LI");
    for (var i=0; i<sfEls.length; i++) {
        sfEls[i].onmouseover=function() {
            this.className+=" sfhover";
        }
        sfEls[i].onmouseout=function() {
            this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp(" sfhover\\b"), "");
        }
    }
}
if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", sfHover);

###################
####### CSS #######
###################
ul#nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    top: 38px;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
ul#nav li {
    position: relative;
}
ul#nav li ul li {
    float: none;
}
/* Links in the drop down lists start */
ul#nav li ul li a {
    clear: left;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #333;
}
/* Links in the drop down lists end */
/* Making visible start */
ul#nav li:hover ul, #nav li.sfhover ul {
    left: auto;
}
/* Making visible end */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to float the container LI's left and set the 'top' value on the pop-up boxes to 100%.
(Tested only in FF3.5)

```
ul#nav li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

ul#nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    top: 100%;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason it's only working in Firefox, or I should say was only working in Firefox since this was posted so long ago, is that IE might need specific pixel locations for the top attribute instead of 100%. I would recommend trying 0px at least for IE, this worked for me recently at least.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't really explain it directly, but I would reccomend adding and subtracting a class attribute, not modifying (getAttribute, removeAttribute, etc.). Also, your class name has a space in it ( " sfhover" ) which probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: I don't know why there is a blank space in the class name. I found this JavaScript code in the tutorial. But it works fine in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
 <li>
    <a>Nav #1</a>
    <ul>
       <li>Nav #1.1</li> 
    <ul>
 </li>
```

To move the entire menu and its submenu. You will have to set float:left at <li> not <a>

```
#menu ul li a { 
    float: none;
}
#menu ul li { 
    float: left;
}
```

One more thing, this doesn't relate to your problem. But, I think you should use display:none/block instead of left:-9999px/auto.

Hope it help.

Comment: My tutorial says: To make the drop down menu work in Opera: "So instead of display: none we use left: -999em to propel the dropdown list out of view and then left: auto (rather than left: 0) to bring it back"

Comment: If you use "display: none", web accessibility devices such as screenreaders (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_reader) won't read the content. By using "left: -999em", you ensure that screen readers can still see the content, even though it's off the page.

Comment: Thank you, medigerati, for the explanation.