# Improve code for drop down menu (HTML/CSS/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

Based on [this tutorial](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/), I've built a drop down menu for [template from Styleshout.com](http://www.styleshout.com/templates/preview/Refresh1-0/index.html). [medigerati helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241915/why-doesnt-this-drop-down-menu-work) so that it works now - at least in Firefox 3.5 and Internet Explorer 8.

[You can see the menu in action here.](http://wp1080088.wp029.webpack.hosteurope.de/Refresh1-1/)

But unfortunately, it doesn't work well in all browsers. In Internet Explorer 6 - for example - it isn't displayed correctly.

Could you please tell me how I can improve the code to make it work in more browsers?

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Nav #1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Nav #1.1</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Nav #1.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Nav #2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Nav #2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav #2.2</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Nav #3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Nav #3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav #3.2</a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul#nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    top: 100%;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
ul#nav li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
/* Links in the drop down lists start */
ul#nav li ul li a {
    clear: left;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #333;
}
/* Links in the drop down lists end */
/* Making visible start */
ul#nav li:hover ul, #nav li.sfhover ul {
    left: auto;
}
/* Making visible end */
```

JavaScript:

```
sfHover = function() {
    var sfEls = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("LI");
    for (var i=0; i<sfEls.length; i++) {
        sfEls[i].onmouseover=function() {
            this.className+=" sfhover";
        }
        sfEls[i].onmouseout=function() {
            this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp(" sfhover\\b"), "");
        }
    }
}
if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", sfHover);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript event binding works differently in different browsers. Try:

```
sfHover = function() {
    var sfEls = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("LI");
    for (var i=0; i<sfEls.length; i++) {
        addEvent(sfEls[i], "mouseover", function() {
            this.className+=" sfhover";
        });
        addEvent(sfEls[i], "mouseout", function() {
            this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp(" sfhover\\b"), "");
        });
    }
}

function addEvent(el, name, func) {
    if (el.attachEvent)
        el.attachEvent("on" + name, func);
    else
        el.addEventListener(name, func, false);
}

addEvent(window, "load", sfHover);
```

[Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/eventSimple.html) has a lot of good articles about events.

Comment: Thank you. But what exactly are the differences between my old code and your new code?

Comment: Notice the addEvent function? That function attaches events in a cross browser compatible way. This is necessary, because not all browsers like `sfEls[i].onmouseout = ` or `element.attachEvent(...)`.

Comment: It doesn't work! At first, I thought it would but not I see that it doesn't. The menus drop down correctly. But they don't close anymore. See here: http://wp1080088.wp029.webpack.hosteurope.de/Refresh1-1/ What can I do? Why is this?

Comment: I think I've got the problem: The JavaScript code adds something to the classname of the LIs. But there was no classname. So I added [class="menueintrag"] everywhere. The class "menueintrag" has no reference in the CSS code but now it seems to work. Is this the correct way of solving the problem? Was this the reason?

Comment: It's possible I guess if `this.className` was returning a null. But I thought it would return an empty string if the attribute wasn't specified. Try using `class=""` instead of `class="menueintrag"`, see if that works too.

Comment: No, this doesn't work. It's a logical error: "menueintrag" + " sfhover" gives "menueintrag sfhover". This is a correct listing of multiple classes. But " " and " sfhover" gives " sfhover" which is a wrong class name since it starts with a blank space.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this as a learning exercise, or do you just want a good nav-bar type menu? If the latter, I would recommend YUI 3.0’s [MenuNav](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/node-menunav/), which is well-tested against all major browsers, including IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Dojo Toolkit toolbar widget](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/Toolbar). Dojo works consistently across all browsers, and even provides accessibility for handicapped users.

The [menu widget](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/test_Menu.html) when anchored to the page (as seen in the example) may also be what you're looking for.